# Excel: Match product id and columns in two sheets and insert data

Tags: excel, vba

I have one big file with about 30 columns and thousands of rows

```
ID           Price         Code          Description  .......
b13          5             1txt          asd          ..
k54          3             2txt1         sad          .. 
m3           2             4asd          asd          ..
a26          6             5add          dsd          ..
```

And another small file with 2 or 3 columns and some hundred rows, it has same ids and some extra ids. Some ids repeat.

```
ID           Price         Code         
b13          5             1txt    
m3           2             4asd    
b13          5             1sdx
```

All I want is that data from small file to be copied (replaced/updated) to the big file in same columns. If some products repeat in small file (as in above example), a new line should be added for that.

The small file will have different columns each time i do this. There should be some generic way.

First I used VLOOKUP , then INDEX and MATCH but I could only manually copy specific information from these files using these. E.g. only one particular column. How can I make it generic? Work for different small files, **match the column name and update it in bigger file**.

Can anyone please give code for it?

I tried Index Match `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))),E2,INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(‌​A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)))`
The problem is that I have to enter it in separate column. Also I have to give the columns to look in (`C:C`) manually

Comment: I tried Index Match `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))),E2,INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)))`

Comment: The problem is that I have to enter it in separate column. Also I have to give the columns to look in (C:C) manually .

Comment: i can't see a way to UPDATE(!) your bigger file without using VBA or a solution with 3 tables (2 source, 1 result). In the ladder case you could use VLOOKUP and IF to select between them, but as you mentioned "thousands" of rows, i would strongly suggest you solve this in someway with database functions.